# Java streams perform different operations by multiple filters

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I want to return different error messages minimum and maximum constraints on the values in a given list. I was hoping to use Java streams but i am having to filter the same list twice. Whereas using a for loop i would only have to go over the list once. Is there a better way to achieve this via streams?

My code looks something like this:

```
list.stream().filter(i -> i < 0).findAny().ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("below min"));

list.stream().filter(i -> i > 100).findAny().ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("above max"));
```

Using a for loop i can place two if conditions while traversing over the list once,

In actual implementation there are other constraints as well and I'm adding an error to a list, if it not already exists, depending on each violation.

Will i have to filter the list each time for each violation?
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Streams have certain areas where they can be useful. Just because you use Java 8 or higher, you don't have to solve everything via streams. Often the classic for-loop is more performant and more readable.

Comment: You're right, just wanted to make sure this is one of those cases and it's not just due to my limited knowledge around streams. thanks!

Comment: To paraphrase a similar situation -- _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think_ “I know, I'll use [streams].”  _Now they have two problems."_  You wouldn't use a hammer when trying to remove a screw, streams (and regular expressions) are tools with specific strengths and weaknesses, and sometime they're just not appropriate.

Comment: Side note: you can write this much simpler: `if(list.stream().anyMatch(i -> i < 0)) System.out.println("below min"); if(list.stream().anyMatch(i -> i > 100)) System.out.println("above max");` Yes, this is “iterating twice” but also stopping at the first match. Why do you think “iterating twice” is a problem?

Comment: @Holger I was just trying to avoid iterating twice because with a list of size n, if below min is at index n-2 and above max is at n-1, it gives a time complexity of 2n, whereas once would be n, I realise constants are not significant but like I mentioned it's actually multiple checks so it would be like O(6n) vs O(n)

Comment: Assuming that the first match of every condition is at the end of the list is far fetched, however, even if it is, the iteration costs of commonly used lists, like `ArrayList` are tiny, even for large lists. When measuring, you may find that in real life, the costs of those more complicated solutions checking multiple conditions at once are actually higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply stream and use a forEach loop to filter out elements in a single loop:

```
        List<Integer> smaller = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> larger = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(200, 345, -132, -2, -34, null);

        intList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(element -> {
            if (element < 0) {
                smaller.add(element);
            } else if (element > 100) {
                larger.add(element);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Smaller:-" + smaller);
        System.out.println("Larger:-" + larger);
```

The real focus should be on code readability even if it takes some more code line to write logic.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Java 12+` you can utilize [teeing collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) to achieve what you want using Java Streams API:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder()),
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder()),
            (min, max) -> {
              min.ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("below min"));
              max.ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("above max"));
              return 0;
            }
    ));
```

You can collect those elements as well:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.filtering(i -> i < 0, Collectors.toList()),
        Collectors.filtering(i -> i > 100, Collectors.toList()),
            (l1, l2) -> {
              System.out.printf("%s %s%n", l1, l2);
              return 0;
            }
    ));
```

Though, whether such approach with streams should be used in place of a `for` loop needs careful consideration. For this specific question, the code using the `for` loop will probably be more readable.

Comment: The original approach stops at the first match whereas this solution has to process the entire list… But if you go this route, use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of `Comparator.comparingInt(Integer.class::cast)`

Comment: Or `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.summarizingInt(i -> i), summary -> { if(summary.getMin() < 0) System.out.println("below min")); if(summary.getMax() > 100) System.out.println("above max")); return 0; }));`

Comment: You are right about stopping iterations on the first match. The first suggestion did not work for me due to compilation issues. The second one worked perfectly. If the input is a list of integers and there is only a need to find min/max it is better.

Comment: Using `(Comparator<Integer>)Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of `Comparator.comparingInt(Integer.class::cast)` worked

Comment: So the problem is the limited type inference. In this case, you can use `Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder()`